# solving for exponent of simple, multi-termed equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Very simple question to answer I expect, but my high-school algebra eludes me...

Consider the simple equation: $$ 1=x^k+y^k$$

How can I re-arrange this to solve for $k$?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any use to the fact that the terms are $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{y}$... reword instead to be $1=x^k+y^k$.  That being said, given specific values for $x$ and $y$, one could use numerical methods to approximate a solution, but I doubt that any clean closed form exists for the general case.

Comment: Thanks - good point. Simplified equation as per suggestion. Surely there is a way to solve using laws of logarithms...

Comment: As for one such technique to approximating the solution for a specific $x$ and $y$, one could use [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  Thankfully, the derivative with respect to $k$ is straightforward to calculate using freshman year calculus.

Comment: Laws of logarithms would not work for this equation since the terms on the RHS are added together

Comment: "*surely there is a way to solve using laws of logarithms*" If the left-hand-side were equal to zero, yes there would be.  You could write as $x^k=-y^k$ and take the logarithm of each side to get $k\ln x = k\ln(-y)$ and then $k=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(-y)}$, however having a nonzero number on the other side complicates things more than you may realize.  $\ln(x^k+y^k)$ does not simplify nicely.  You have $\ln(a\cdot b)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ but there is no good way to rewrite $\ln(a+b)$.  [Even wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+in+1%3D2%5Ex%2B5%5Ex) gives approximations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one can work as follows:

1. If $x>1$ and $y>1$, then it follows that 
   $$f(k)=x^k+y^k-1$$
   is strictly increasing, so, it has at most one root. Note that $$f(0)=1>0$$ so this root, let $k_0$, should be lesser than $0$. Now, also note that
   $$\lim_{k\to-\infty}f(k)=0+0-1=-1<0$$
   so, by the Intermediate Values Theorem, we have that there exist a $k_0\in(-\infty,0)$ such that 
   $$f(k_0)=0$$
   As for the exact value of $x_0$, as commented, you can approximate it with any numerical method.
2. If $x<1,y<1$, you can work in the same way.
3. If $x<1<y$, then $x^k$ is strictly decreasing and $y^k$ is strictly increasing, so,for $k<0$ we have that 
   $$x^k>1\Rightarrow x^k+y^k-1>0$$
   and for $k>0$:
   $$y^k>1\Rightarrow x^k+y^k-1>0$$
   So 
   $$f(k)\neq0$$
   Which means that the equation has no solution for $x<1<y$ (or, symmetrically $y<1<x$).

Comment: In the situation I am applying it, $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$and $k>0$

Comment: I suppose, but have not yet proved, that the solution is in the form of 
$$k=\lambda(x,y)\log_x(A(x,y))+\lambda(x,y)\log_y(B(x,y))$$ where $\lambda(x,y\in[0,1])$. However, I'm not yet sure about that...